# Run a function when all images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a function like this to load images from an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images_list.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                images_objects.push(this);
                showImages(images_objects);
            };
            img.onerror = function() {

            };
            img.src = images_links[i].image_url;
        }
```

What I need to make work properly is `showImages` function. Its purpose is to show all loaded images with jQuery when the `images_object` is filled with images from the array. Now it's placed incorrectly, just to give you an idea how I try to do it. I suppose there is something like a callback should be run after the images are loaded. How to do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a helper function to store the newly loaded image and to check to see if all images have been loaded, might work.

```
...
img.onload = function() {
    storeLoadedImage(this);
};
...

var storeLoadedImage = function(image) {
    images_objects.push(image);

    if (images_objects.length === images_list.length) {
        showImages(images_objects);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use it inside the loop. It will show all images loaded till ith iteration and not all loaded images if that's what you're trying to say. 
Just add this as the first line of the loop

```
if (i==images_list.length) {showImages(images_objects);}
```

What I understand is you want to display them once all of them have been loaded.